# Подсчет файлов Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache, jms, camel

Есть вот такой маршрут. Необходимо при обработке каждого 100 файла выводить лог. Не могу понять как организовать подсчет файлов. Файлы с разными расширениями и нужно выводить сколько какого обработалось + еще время обработки этой сотни файлов...

```
public void configure() {
        from("file:data?noop=true")
                .choice()
                    .when().simple("${file:name} endsWith 'xml'")
                        .log("Xml файл обрабатывается процессором")
                        .process(xmlFileProcessor)
                        .log("Xml файл отправляется в очередь")
                    .to("activemq:test")
                    .when().simple("${file:name} endsWith 'txt'")
                        .log("Txt файл обрабатывается процессором")
                        .process(txtFileProcessor)
                        .log("Txt файл отправляется в очередь")
                    .to("activemq:test")
                        .endChoice()
                    .otherwise()
                        .log("Файл с каким-то расширением обрабатывается процессором")
                        .process(otherwiseFileProcessor)
                        .log("Файл с каким-то расширением отправляется в очередь invalide")
                    .to("activemq:invalid-queue")
                        .log("Выбрасывается исключение")
                        .throwException(new BadExpansion("Неверное расширение"))
                    .when(PredicateBuilder.constant((countXml + countTxt + countOther) % 100 == 0))
                        .log("Количество файлов 100")
                        .log("Количество файлов txt " + countTxt + "\n" +
                        "Количество файлов xml " + countXml + "\n" +
                        "Количество остальных файлов " + countOther + "\n" +
                        "Время обработки сообщений " )
                    .end();
```

Со временем вообще не разобрался как сделать можно, а вот с подсчетом файлов была такая идея, реализовать классы процессы для каждого расширения типа вот этого

```
public class XmlFileProcessor implements Processor {
public static long countXmlFile = 0;
@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) {
    ++countXmlFile;
}
```

}

Но он инкрементируется только в пределах класса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось все куда проще. Нужно было сделать один класс процессор (а не плодить для каждого расширения свой) и в нем уже проводить все действия со всеми расширениями. Примерно так

```
public class ExtensionProcessor implements Processor {

private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

private static final long BATCH_FILES = 100;
private static final String EXT_TXT = "txt";
private static final String EXT_XML = "xml";
private static final String EXT_ANOTHER = "ext_another";

private static Map<String, Long> countByTypeFiles;
private static long startTimeHandlingBatchFiles = 0;
private static long countFiles = 0;
private static boolean isStartHandlingBatchFiles = true;

static {
    countByTypeFiles = new HashMap<>();
    countByTypeFiles.put(EXT_TXT, 0L);
    countByTypeFiles.put(EXT_XML, 0L);
    countByTypeFiles.put(EXT_ANOTHER, 0L);
}

@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    if(isStartHandlingBatchFiles) {
        startTimeHandlingBatchFiles = System.currentTimeMillis();
        isStartHandlingBatchFiles = false;
    }
    handlingMessage(exchange);
    countFiles++;

    if (countFiles % BATCH_FILES == 0){
        logger.info("------------------------------------------------");
        logger.info("Количество файлов txt " + countByTypeFiles.get(EXT_TXT));
        logger.info("Количество файлов xml " + countByTypeFiles.get(EXT_XML));
        logger.info("Количество остальных файлов " + countByTypeFiles.get(EXT_ANOTHER));
        logger.info("Время обработки сообщений " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTimeHandlingBatchFiles));
        logger.info("------------------------------------------------");
        isStartHandlingBatchFiles = true;
    }

}

private String getFileName(Exchange exchange) {
    return exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME).toString();
}

private String getExtensionFile(String fileName) {
    return FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileName);
}

private String getBody(Exchange exchange) {
    return exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
}

private void handlingMessage(Exchange exchange) {
    String fileName = getFileName(exchange);

    String extensionFile = getExtensionFile(fileName);

    if (extensionFile.equals(EXT_TXT) || extensionFile.equals(EXT_XML)) {
        incrementCountFiles(extensionFile);
    } else {
        incrementCountFiles(EXT_ANOTHER);
    }

    if (extensionFile.equals(EXT_TXT)) {
        String body = getBody(exchange);
        saveBodyMessageDB(body);
    }
}

private void incrementCountFiles(String extensionFile) {
    long count = countByTypeFiles.get(extensionFile);
    countByTypeFiles.put(extensionFile, ++count);
}


private void saveBodyMessageDB(String body) {
    PropertyLoader propertyLoader = new PropertyLoader(RESOURCES);
    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            propertyLoader.getConnectionURL(),
            propertyLoader.getUser(),
            propertyLoader.getPassword())) {
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL)) {
            preparedStatement.setString(1, body);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            connection.commit();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            connection.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (SQLException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}